# How to make a wall post on a community page (as owner of the page) in Facebook?

Tags: php, facebook

I have looked at the developers' page but there tons of tons stuff. Application authentication (will my PHP called app?), setting permissions, how to make post after authentication?, where to store authentication? etc etc and so on I wasn't able to get all what all they mean, and what is need in all that stuff.

I only want to make a wall post to the community/fan page's wall as community/fan page. What steps should my PHP application follow to make a wall post?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Post on a Facebook wall as Page, not as user](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/5326537/post-on-a-facebook-wall-as-page-not-as-user)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've written an in-depth tutorial about this subject: [How To: Post On Facebook Page As Page Not As Admin User Using PHP-SDK](http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/how-to-post-on-facebook-page-as-page-not-as-admin-user-using-php-sdk/31/)

In short:

1. You need at least the `publish_stream` and `manage_pages` [permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/)
2. Query your [`page`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/) object to get a *page access token*
3. And post!

A starting code from my tutorial:

```
<?php
// This code is just a snippet of the example.php script
// from the PHP-SDK <http://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php>
require '../src/facebook.php';

// Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'app_id',
  'secret' => 'app_secret',
));

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
  try {
    $page_id = 'page_id';
    $page_info = $facebook->api("/$page_id?fields=access_token");
    if( !empty($page_info['access_token']) ) {
        $args = array(
            'access_token'  => $page_info['access_token'],
            'message'       => "I'm a Page!"
        );
        $post_id = $facebook->api("/$page_id/feed","post",$args);
    }
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}

// Login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope'=>'manage_pages,publish_stream'));
}
?>
```

Note: *you may need the `offline_access` if you want to post while you are not connected to Facebook (e.g.: from your CMS)*